# Alamofire Error In xCode 7 data object

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, alamofire

So i just updated to xCode 7 opened my xCode project and of course it all went to hell.  Ive imported the new Alamofire.xcodeproj and linked the proper binaries.  My old code to get data from web service was this and i can't figure out why it doesn't like it?

Error:
Tuple types '(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?,......

My original Alamofire request is below?  How do i modify to get the results with with what i think is swift 2, Xcode 7 and latest alamorefire.xcodeproj?

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: ["vID": emptyString, "action": "GetDetails"])
            .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
                //print(data)
                // print(request)

                let json = JSON(object: data!)
                if let appName = json[0]["vTitle"].stringValue {
                    //self.items.removeAtIndex(0)
                    let dataArray = data as NSArray;



                    for item in dataArray { // loop through data items

                        var vTitle = item["vTitle"] as String
                        var vLocation = item["vLocation"] as String
                        var vID = item["vID"] as String


                        //self.items.append([sTitle, sID])

                        self.vendorLabel.text = vTitle
                        self.locationLabel.text = vLocation

                        self.vendorLabelIPad.text = vTitle
                        self.vendorLabelIPad.text = vLocation


                        let obj = item as NSDictionary

                    }



                }

        }
```

Comment: Error: which you have truncated holds the key. Probably there is no error parameter anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your responseJSON should have different parameters:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
         .responseJSON { _, _, result in
             print(result)
             debugPrint(result)
         }
```

Comment: How do i retrieve the data?  dubugPrint(result) returns SUCCESS: (
        {
        "date_string" = What;
        vcID = 1;
        vcTitle = "Indoor Snacks & Candy";
    },
        {
        "date_string" = What;
        vcID = 2;
        vcTitle = "Community Service Groups";
    },
        {
        "date_string" = What;
        vcID = 3;
        vcTitle = "Outdoor Food - Pizza";
    },
        {
        "date_string" = What;
        vcID = 4;
        vcTitle = "Indoor - Clothing ";
    }
)